# Openwrt in bridge mode - ebtables kernel error

Tags: networking, iptables, openwrt, ebtables

I have a setup at home as follow:

```
DHCP clients  -----> (wifi)(bridge) Openwrt -----> (eth)Main Router
```

The device I'm using is TPlink MR3020 with Barrier Breaker and I tried to set up transparent proxy for bridge traffic - I want to redirect the packets passing through the bridge to proxy server(`privoxy`). I tried to use `ebtables`. But when I enter the following command:

```
ebtables -t broute -A BROUTING -p IPv4 --ip-protocol 6 --ip-destination-port 80 -j redirect --redirect-target ACCEPT
```

I got following error:

```
Unable to update the kernel. Two possible causes:
1. Multiple ebtables programs were executing simultaneously. The ebtables
userspace tool doesn't by default support multiple ebtables programs running
concurrently. The ebtables option --concurrent or a tool like flock can be
used to support concurrent scripts that update the ebtables kernel tables.
2. The kernel doesn't support a certain ebtables extension, consider
recompiling your kernel or insmod the extension.
```

I tried to activate the IPv4 package with `insmod`, but no luck.

Any ideas on how to accomplish this?